# Making value of variable from database

Tags: php

I know it's easy for you but it's not for me.

I have database where I have some rows like id, username, permission etc.

What I want to do with this is to make variable have same value that my "permission" says so.

```
$perm = "SELECT permission FROM `user` WHERE username='ochmar'";
$permission = mysql_query($perm);
echo  "". $permission . "";
```

Got something like this, but... it says "Resource id #5", when permission is just number 1-3. (It should say "2", but says this weird for me stuff).
Anyone can help me?

Comment: pro tip, stop using mysql_*

Comment: you should consider skipping straight to mysqli or pdo so you don't have to unlearn the bad habits taught by mysql. also the quotes are unecessary if you are simply echoing a variable. `echo $permission;` will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually fetch your result:

```
$perm = "SELECT permission FROM `user` WHERE username='ochmar'";
$result= mysql_query($perm);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['permission'];
```